# Import / export license for software development outsourcing

Tags: legal, outsourcing

If I am based in the united States and outsourcing a software application development work to a individual in India. Do I need a import license or does he need to have a export license for me to be able to use and sell that software application which he has developed for me?

Comment: No, you do not.

Answer (score 1):

If you or he needs a license then there are thousands of unlicensed projects out there. I highly doubt it and if you do require a license, I expect all the freelancer sites would have some sort of revenue angle to promote the necessity for a license if one were in fact needed.